# How to compress log files automatically and delete after x days?

Tags: logging, log4net, enterprise-library, log4net-configuration

I'm developing a software, which using log4net and enterpriselibrary.logging to log the operations. After 2 hours i got about a 100mb large log files(file names contain the current date), but i want to compress them daily using the logger environment. Is it possible or should i implement a log compresser? (the problems are the client-side logs)

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious if you *need* to log so much data? (It seems like a lot for transitory data.)  What do you mean by "logger environment"? Maybe the easiest way is to start a long running background task to compress and delete if you need that logic to run within your client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i was looking for is exactly this:

```
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=foo.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz
```

But this method not supported by log4net & enterprise library, so i had to implement my 'log-backup' operation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). This utility is designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks,but im developing in c#/.Net so im using windows and this is for linux and i want to use the logger environments.